# How do I change pylint to look for doxygen comments instead of docstrings?

Tags: python, doxygen, pylint

When I pylint my code, pylint warns about missing docstring for some function or member function.  That is, it complains about missing '''function comment'''.

My company uses doxygen's comment blocks that begin with ##  and comes before the definition of the function.  We don't use docstrings for commenting.

Aside from turning off missing docstring warning, is there anyway to tell pylint, hey instead of looking for '''...''' and complaining that it is missing, look for doxygen comment blocks that begin with ## before the function/member function and complain if such a block is missing.

thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such possibility yet. You may submit a feature request (or even better, a pull request) on https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint

Comment: Hey sthenault.  Thanks for this comment.  Is there a way to submit the request anonymously?  I don't want to risk my real email being traced back to my stackoverflow postings.    Thanks.